# Why is my object null when trying to parse a json string to said object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm trying to parse some json data which looks like this:

```
{
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Cannonball",
    "members": true,
    "sp": 5,
    "buy_average": 172,
    "buy_quantity": 210800,
    "sell_average": 174,
    "sell_quantity": 326435,
    "overall_average": 174,
    "overall_quantity": 537235
  },
  "6": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Cannon base",
    "members": true,
    "sp": 187500,
    "buy_average": 185130,
    "buy_quantity": 1,
    "sell_average": 181300,
    "sell_quantity": 3,
    "overall_average": 182257,
    "overall_quantity": 4
  }
}
```

And I'm using the following model

```
class BuySellModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool members { get; set; }
    public int sp { get; set; }
    public int buy_average { get; set; }
    public int buy_quantity { get; set; }
    public int sell_average { get; set; }
    public int sell_quantity { get; set; }
    public int overall_average { get; set; }
    public int overall_quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Now the way I am trying to parse it is by using JSON.NET in order to get each and every single item as a .NET object in a collection of some sort, so kinda like `List<BuySellModel>`

However.. When I try parsing it doing this

```
var BuySellObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuySellModel>(buySellDataString);
```

each property in `BuySellObjects` is then null and I don't understand why.

Could someone explain why each property is null and here I went wrong?

Comment: those properties other than `name` can't be null.

Comment: your json string has an object with a `2` property and a `6` property.

Comment: Oh! I see that now, but how do I go about solving that? Would it be a model with a model inside it some how? A bit confused

Answer (score 3):

Try using this as your model

```
    public class ParsableModel
    {
       public Dictionary<int, BuySellModel> BuySellObjects { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your json looks like a dictionary of int and BuySellModel

you can try this

```
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<int, BuySellModel>>(buySellDataString);
var allBuySellObjects = dictionary.Values; // flatten all the values into a list
```